# Python routing traffic through tor

Tags: python, networking, tor

i am trying to make a script that routes my traffic through TOR.But an error occurred i can't solve.

script's code:

```
import socket
import socks
import stem.process
import requests
import time

def start_tor(tor_path='C:\\PATH-TO-TOR\\TorBrowser\\Tor\\tor.exe'):
  tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd=tor_path,
    config = {
      'SocksPort': str(9050)
    },
  )
  return tor_process

def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
  sock = socks.socksocket()
  sock.connect(address)
  return sock

# start TOR
tor_process = start_tor('C:\\PATH-TO-TOR\\TorBrowser\\Tor\\tor.exe')

# patch the socket module
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

print('Rooting all your device traffic through TOR Relays')
while True:
    print('TOR is running')
    response = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/ip")
    print("Connected to:", response.text)
    time.sleep(10)
    tor_process.signal(stem.Signal.NEWNYM)
```

the error that it prints is:

```
File "c:\Users\User\Documents\test3.py", line 36, in <module>
tor_process.signal(stem.Signal.NEWNYM)
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

**Basically in the line 36 i want to change ip (every 3 minutes as i have in my code)**

Comment: There's no method called *signal*. Did you mean https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal?

Comment: BTW, [the `stem.Signal` docs](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.Signal) indicate that _some_ signals map to things you can send with `Popen.send_signal`, but not all of them, and specifically not `NEWNYM`. You need a `stem.control.Controller`, not a Popen object, to do a newnym. (Also, you can only do NEWNYM with a certain frequency; beyond that it's just ignored).

Comment: See `Controller.from_port` or `Controller.from_socket_file` to get a handle that can be used for the request.